# Convergence in $r$-th mean when $r$ is infinity

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

For random variable $X_n$ which satisfies $-1<X_n<1$ for all $n$,

then can we say that $X_n$ converges to $0$ in $r$-th mean for all-natural number $r$??

This is because when $r$ goes to infinity, $E|X_n|^r$ goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know whether convergence in rth mean includes infinitely large r. Thats all